# React JS - How to pass different props into a map of other props

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components

**Question: How can I pass this `params` array into my `<Post />` component with the `data` array being mapped?** 
my state has two arrays. `this.state = { data: [], params: [] };` and I passed them down via props to a file called PostList.js. It renders every post (from the data array ) in a map function, see below:

```
//PostList.js
//.....Removed for brevity....
render(){
    // Tried let params = this.props.params; HERE
    let socialPostNodes = this.props.data.map(socialPost => {
        // Tried let params = this.props.params; HERE
        return (
            <Post
                //I need params = { this.props.params } HERE
                messageNumber = { socialPost.message.indexOf('', 1) }
                message={ socialPost.message}
                uniqueID={ socialPost['_id'] }
                key={ socialPost['_id'] } >
                { socialPost.message }
            </Post>
        )
    });
//.....removed for brevity......
```

I need to put the `this.props.params` into `<Post />` so I can reference them inside the Post.js file, but I don't know how and can't find the answer.

If I attempt to add `let params = this.props.params;` after `render()` or even before `return(...` , the props aren't obtained. This means I can't put `<Post params={ params }... </Post>`.

Question: How can I pass this `params` array into my `<Post />` component with the `data` array being mapped?

If you're wondering:
- There is data in the arrays
- Passing down from the parent component was successful
- the Post.js file successfully does what I need
- I am new to reactJS
- I can put more of the file in, just ask
Thank you!

**EDIT**
Added Post.js file
It looks for {{company}} inside the post message and replaces it with the string 'company'

```
class Post extends Component {
    loadInParams() {
        let socialMessage = this.props.message;
        if (socialMessage.indexOf("{{company}}") >= 0) {
            let newSocialMessage = socialMessage.replace("{{company}}", 'company')
            return newSocialMessage
        } else {
            let newSocialMessage = socialMessage;
            return newSocialMessage
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h4> Post { this.props.messageNumber } </h4>
                <strong>Post Template: </strong> { this.props.message }
                <br />
                <strong>Ready Post: </strong>
                { this.loadInParams() }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: @kevin-danikowski i think we got confused. Could you show me the part where you are passing `this.state.data` and `this.state.params` ? It should be in your `Parent` component which is importing the component being exported from `Postlist.js`.

Comment: @keshavDulal gravityplanx was able to solve it, I passed it like this:    ...         <PostList data={ this.state.data } params={ this.state.params }/> ...

Comment: Yeah... exactly. That's what I wanted to make sure of. Anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` scope is lost when you enter `map`!  But the `map` function allows you to provide a second argument to provide the `this` context.

E.g.;

```
this.props.data.map(socialPost => {
    ...
}, this);
```

Passing in that second argument will allow you to access the parent scope's `this`, meaning that `this.props.params` will now have values.